# Revenuecat Firebase Webhook Cloud Function Security

Tags: revenuecat, firebase-extensions

Is Revenuecat Firebase Cloud Function endpoint exposed to users? Can client side see the endpoint link or is it triggered from Apple-Google payment service?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Revenuecat support;

> The endpoint would not be exposed to users, just used for the
> communication between RevenueCat and Firebase, and triggered when an
> event is triggered by one of the stores.